# RazorEngine extension methods in a template

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

I am using the Razor engine: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine.

I am creating a model dynamically. I'm trying to include a extension method in a template but it inst recognising the extension class. I am receiving the following error message " **'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToUpperFirstLetter'** "

**Model Creation**

```
dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<string, object>)model).Add("Forename", "john");
```

**Template**

```
@using Namespace.Extensions
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}

Hello @Model.Forename.ToUpperFirstLetter()
```

**Extension Class**

```
namespace Namespace.Extensions
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
         public static string ToUpperFirstLetter(this string source)
         {
             return ....removed for abbreviation
         }
    }
}
```

**Razor Parsing**

```
ITemplate template = Razor.Resolve(template, model);
string result = template.Run(new ExecuteContext());
```

**Edit**

I also wanted to create an extension method on the Dynamic ExpandoObject. To see if a value inside the Model exists. I am receiving the following error message "**System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue'**"

**Extension Class**

```
public static class ExpandoObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool HasValue(this ExpandoObject source, string key)
    {
        return ((IDictionary<String, object>)source).ContainsKey(key);
    }
}
```

**Extension Use**

```
@if(Model.HasValue("Hello"))
{ 
    @Model.Hello
}
```

**EDIT TWO**

The below works and goes into the extension method

```
var o = new object();
var bool = o.HasValue("value");
```

The dynamic model still throws an exception - **RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue'**

```
dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
var bool = model.HasValue("value");
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're seeing is that you're trying to execute a method `ToUpperFirstLetter(this string source)` when in reality, the `Forename` property is `dynamic`. I would imagine if you did something like:

```
@(((string)Model.Forename).ToUpperFirstLetter())
```

... it would probably work. This is all down to the use of `dynamic`. Dynamic is handled at runtime through late binding, but as RazorEngine is *compiling* your view, it's trying to statically link the method that expects a string where you're providing dynamic. The compiler doesn't know that `Forename` is a string.

You also **cannot** have a `dynamic` first argument to an extension method, e.g.:

```
public static string ToUpperFirsLetter(this dynamic source) { ... }
```

Because extension methods are resolved at compile time to explicit method calls, but the compiler doesn't know how to handle dynamic first arguments in extension methods.

**EDIT**
Based on your response, if you want to achieve these sort of extension methods where dynamic might be the type, you'll be better of using `object` and testing for types, e.g.:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
  public static string ToUpperFirstLetter(this object val)
  {
    string str = val as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(str)) return str;

    return str.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + str.Substring(1);
  }
}

public static class ExpandoObjectExtensions
{
  public static bool HasValue(this object val, string key)
  {
    var expando = val as ExpandoObject;
    if (expando == null) return false;

    return ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando).ContainsKey(key);
  }
}
```

... Not ideal, but it is still a typesafe way of using extension methods on `dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also wanted to provide an extension method on ExpandoObject to see if the Model contains a value. Is there an easier way of achieving this, rather than how uve described above? See edit above

Comment: You suffer from the same issue, but see edit for an alternative solution.

Comment: It still cant find the extension method on a dynamic object. See update. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I'm becoming unconvinced about extension methods and `dynamic`. You might only be able to call it as `ExpandoObjectExtensions.HasValue(value, key)`.

Comment: Ye it appears your correct. Extension methods aren't possible on a dynamic object and the solution is to use a static method instead.